# Possible to use Windows tablet touchscreen with the screen off?

Tags: c#, touch

I want to turn off Windows tablet screen, keep a (C#/WPF) program running, and turn it back on via touch. The reason is to save power when the user is not interacting with the touchscreen.

I've looked through a lot of WIN32 API stuff, WMI stuff, and forums, and cannot find if it is possible or if it is even possible.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't mean to be insulting, but why not let the built in Windows power management to turn off the display after a period of time?

Comment: Because then touch does not work to alert the app someone wants the program to respond.

I have an embedded kiosk tablet and the running app draws too much power. I wanted to turn of the screen to save power when not in use, but all a user can interact with is the touchscreen to get the app to turn the screen back on for use.